# (Windows)Can I get the program to be changed or be stopped while it is running?

Tags: c++, winapi, interrupt

I am now writing a win32 program in C++.
I want to show my running process on the window, just like time is flowing.

For example, this code

```
int a=0;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  a++;//The change in "a" can be seen on the window.
  Sleep(1*1000);
}
```

But I've found that if I want to show this process, like clicking a button and a changing number appears on the screen, then the program needs to be running all the time. At this point, I don't have a way to do anything else, like clicking on another button.

So I realized I needed an operation that could interrupt the current process. But I went through a lot of information and found that only the fork() function of the Linux system can meet my needs. But I'm using Windows now, so what other ways can I achieve this?
Sincerely look forward to your reply.

Comment: You might want to use threads (e.g.: `std::thread`)? At least that's what it sounds like to me

Comment: Although I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "interrupt the current process"? What exactly do you want to interrupt? Do you mean to cancel the operation in progress?

Comment: @UnholySheep you usually cannot update the interface from anywhere but the GUI thread.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: The worker thread could post a `WM_USER` message with the value `a` to the GUI thread.

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm going to get to know thread, maybe that's what I want, thanks!
Interrupting a process can be like suddenly executing another thing while a loop is in progress, and then another thing starts and the current progression terminates.

Comment: @MSalters yes, that is a way around. It's a good solution if that thread is going to do heavy computation and post the result to the GUI thread. For something like ++a, it's rather wasteful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to create a timer with [SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer). Then watch for the [WM_TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer) messages and update the screen then. This is the standard way of achieving what you described.

Comment: Correct. Microsoft Windows works with messages - the button clicks in the question are also messages; painting the UI happens in response to messages. Timer messages fit right in.

Comment: The reason this works is that the rest of your program can still do stuff for 1 second - whereas Sleep makes the whole program wait.

Comment: @user253751: `Sleep` makes only the current thread wait. Still, that is very bad when the current thread is the GUI thread.

Answer (score -2):

Create a thread and use atomic.

```
std::atomic_int a_t(0);

auto do_a = [](std::atomic_int* pA)
{
for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
{
    (*pA)++;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}
};

thread t(do_a, &a_t);
t.join();
cout << a_t.load(memory_order::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Anytime you need get the value of `a_t` , just call  `a_t.load(memory_order::memory_order_relaxed);`

Hope this helps you

Comment: Showing the result with `std::cout` at the end is missing the point of the question. How do you show the data live, in Windows?

Comment: `t.join()` is an awesome way to waste resources. Why spin up a thread when you're immediately waiting for it to terminate? That's synchronous programming, just with the added minus point of spinning up a thread.